# Where can I find Postgresql dump file?

Tags: database, postgresql, dump

I use this command to create dump file from Postgresql database

```
pg_dump rulings > rulings.sql
```

But I can not find any SQL dump file from 
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin

Command-line does not say anything about it, therefore I can not see if there is any error.

How can I find it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the dump file is created in the current directory, ie. the directory where `pg_dump` has been started. if this is run a script, check the directory used in the script.

Comment: I run this code from psql logging in targetted Database name.

pg_dump rulings > rulings.sql

In this case where the dump file is created??